# How to make react-select options scrollable

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a list of options in being displayed in react-select. Since this component is at the lower edge of the screen the items tend to get cut off from the screen.

I noticed the selection lists provided in the official react-select provided has a scroll bar. I have tried looking at the docs and the GitHub page but i still couldn't figure out a solution.

The below image shows how my react-select options list is displayed.

[image: This is how my react-select options list is displayed]

My question is how do i make the list displayed to be scrollable.

The following is the code I have used.

```
import Select from 'react-select';

const SearchSelect = (props) => {
  const { options, defaultValue, onChange, name, label } = props;
  return (
    <>
      {label && <label htmlFor="search-select">{label}</label>}
      <Select
        options={options}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        onChange={onChange}
        name={name}
        id="search-select"
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

The option values are initially taken from an API and are passed into this component from the parent.

Comment: Menu list has a default overflow-y value to `true`. Please make sure you don't overwrite it somehow.

Comment: Can you please share what custom css styles do you apply to the select component?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help @JordanEnev . The issue seems to have been that the default maxMenuHeight wasn't triggering the scroll, after putting a lesser value the scroll works. :D

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can play with the `maxMenuHeight` prop:

```
<Select maxMenuHeight={250} />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The issue seems to have been that the default maxMenuHeight wasn't triggering the scroll, after putting a lesser value the scroll works. :D

Answer (score 5):

```
const menuPortalTarget = document.getElementById('root');
<Select
    maxMenuHeight={220}
    menuPlacement="auto"
    menuPortalTarget={menuPortalTarget}
/>
```

[image]

`maxMenuHeight` - limit your menu height to the given input in my case it limits at 220px and then you can see in image scroll bar is added.

`menuPlacement` - it can show your menu above or below your select input according to available space in `auto`

Comment: please provide a little description for your answer too

Comment: @Leonardo Thanks for your advice.